# Nginx error.log message trimmed - How to increase string print size?

Tags: php, nginx, fastcgi, error-logging

I have successfully migrated an ecommerce store from Apache to the following set up:

- nginx/1.8.1
- PHP 5.6.17 (fpm-fcgi) using PHP-fpm to interconnect
- Prestashop 1.6.1.4
- Amazon Linux AMI release 2015.09

We are trying to find the root cause of a problem in the webstore which seems to be related to some errors we have after viewing the product single page.

The Nginx error.log is capturing this error, but comparing to the other messages I have on the error log it seems that it's either incomplete or missing information on this specific message.

Let me show you.

This is a 'normal' error/notice message:

> 2016/04/08 17:59:17 [error] 20556#0: *1174 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP     message: PHP Notice:  Undefined index: img_color_exists in /data/www/www.webstore.com/cache/smarty/compile/bd/cf/99/bdcf9912784a814902d87f2da1cc546547993df8.file.product.tpl.php on line 483

This is the message we are trying to track down:

> 2016/04/08 18:01:05 [error] 20556#0: *1192 FastCGI sent in stderr: "oduct-list.tpl.php on line 52

Isn't there a configuration of Nginx or something that I could do to get further information regarding this error?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Best regards,